# Error 400 Bad Request when accessing Twitch API from Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, discord.py, twitch

This is my code for my Discord bot to access Twitch API and see if any streamers in the "Twitch_channels.txt" document are live. It worked well for a while but then I started getting this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GAMING-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\GAMING-PC\Documents\Discord bot\Discord-bot\SAMURAI.py", line 75, in on_ready
    await onlinecheck(onlines)
  File "C:\Users\GAMING-PC\Documents\Discord bot\Discord-bot\SAMURAI.py", line 54, in onlinecheck
    if len(stream_data['data']) == 1:
KeyError: 'data'
```

This is the code, it takes the names from a text document and then accesses Twitch API to see if that channel is live or not:

```py
async def onlinecheck(onlines):
    check = False
    if check == False:
        channels = open('Twitch channels.txt')
        lines = channels.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            entry = line.split(',')
            server = client.get_channel(int(entry[0]))
            channel = str(entry[1])
            client_id = 'k6hsyhu5xdr78uwtloku6slque6sxj'
            client_secret = 'secret goes here'
            streamer_name = channel
            body = {
                'client_id': client_id,
                'client_secret': client_secret,
                "grant_type": 'client_credentials'
            }
            r = requests.post('https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token', body)
            keys = r.json();
            headers = {
                'Client-ID': client_id,
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + keys['access_token']
            }
            stream = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login=' + streamer_name, headers=headers)
            stream_data = stream.json()
            print(stream_data)
            if len(stream_data['data']) == 1:
                if channel not in onlines:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{channel} is streaming!",description=f"[link](https://www.twitch.tv/{channel})")
                    await server.send(embed=embed)
                    onlines.append(channel)
            else:
                if channel in onlines:
                    onlines.remove(channel)
            check = True
    await asyncio.sleep(240)
    check = False
```

When I print the **stream_data** it prints this:

```
{'error': 'Bad Request', 'status': 400, 'message': 'Malformed query params.'}
```

I don't know if it's something on my side as this worked before, or if it's something to do with the API.

Comment: Does `streamer_name` contain characters that are not valid in a URL?

Comment: @IainShelvington No, at the moment the only channels are `jackledoodles_tv` and `rogue_console`.

Answer (score 0):

A [`400 Bad Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) means that the server will **`not`** process the request due to a `client` error (for example, malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)

In your case, the message says `Malformed query params`. I suggest you check the [Twitch API](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/) documentation again. If the code worked for a while but stopped suddenly, the API requirements likely changed.

In conclusion, reread the API documentation and check for code errors (such as syntax)

Cheers